# Pandas Error- Why are my objects of mixed type?

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to store a data frame into an hdf5 file, but when I enter the command

```
 subInfo.to_hdf('storage.h5', 'd1', mode = 'a', append = True, format = 
 'table')
```

I get the error message:

```
Cannot serialize the column [pairs] because its data contents are [mixed] 
object dtype
```

For reference, in the data frame I am working with, the column `'pairs'` only contains length 2 tuples.  How do I fix this issue?

Sample data:

```
            pairs          r                    r1  
0          (179, 180)   0.928479   [17.671, 19.8573, 27.1782]   
1          (179, 445)  21.189453   [17.671, 19.8573, 27.1782]   
2         (179, 1052)  25.448198   [17.671, 19.8573, 27.1782]   
3         (179, 1683)  16.970432   [17.671, 19.8573, 27.1782]   
4         (179, 1684)  16.927219   [17.671, 19.8573, 27.1782]   
5         (179, 1852)   8.293519   [17.671, 19.8573, 27.1782]
```

Comment: Without sample data, no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its not an issue you can simple convert the datatype for the pandas dataframe into a string and it will store as required.

Also if the Data is int and float you can use the same code to convert the dataframe to the same kind of data types.

```
subInfo.astype(str).to_hdf('storage.h5', 'd1', mode = 'a', append = True, format = 'table')
```

you can split the list in the column r1 into different columns with the following code:

```
subInfo[["new1","new2","new3"]]=pd.DataFrame(subInfo.r1.values.tolist(),index=subInfo.index)
```

**do keep in mind that the number of columns should be equal to the elements in the list or a tuple**

similarly you can split the tuple in the first column named pairs into two different columns with a similar code as well:

```
subInfo[["new4","new5"]]=pd.DataFrame(subInfo.pairs.values.tolist(),index=subInfo.index)
```

Comment: Will I notice any performance issues with conversion to string? Also what do I have to do differently to read it back into its original format?

Comment: no issues in reading as such you can simply do a pd.read_hdf("name of file")

Comment: you can change datatypes as you want for any operation with a `df.astype(float)` etc

Comment: for further details on df.astype you can also look at this documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html or simply ask here will be happy to help :)

Comment: If I need to use `df.astype(float)` when reading the file, why could't I save it like that? `subInfo.astype(float).to_hdf('storage.h5', 'd1', mode = 'a', append = True, format = 'table')` instead of `subInfo.astype(str).to_hdf('storage.h5', 'd1', mode = 'a', append = True, format = 'table')`?

Comment: no you don't have to use anything to read the file, its just if you need to perform operations outside pandas, most operations in pandas will work as normal

Comment: it may raise an error for the tuple or a list if you will try to convert it to float as your dataframe contains tuples and lists and that is the reason why it can't be saved

Comment: I tried converting to string and that seems to add a decent amount of time (I am appending to a file iteratively so I want to be efficient with each step). I tried converting the pairs column to numpy arrays but it still kicks out the same error. Is there a way to split these arrays into separate columns efficiently?

Comment: Converting all my arrays into columns of floats seems to work well. Thanks for your help!